# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION when instantiating a Realm Object

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a Realm object called Dog:

```
import RealmSwift

class Dog: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var age = 0
}
```

However, when I try to instantiate it

```
let myDog = Dog()
```

I'm getting this error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

I also get this in the All Output window but I'm not sure if it's causing the crash:

> SampleApp[25047:274257] *** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x10ba06d20 of class 'SDK.Dog' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- did you forget to declare the superclass of 'SDK.Dog'?
>
> 2018-12-06 14:02:06.243187-0600 SampleApp[25047:274257] *** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x10ba06d20 of class 'SDK.Dog' does not implement doesNotRecognizeSelector: -- abort

Here's the SDK's linked frameworks and libraries, I needed to make them optional to get the SampleApp to build.

[image]

Comment: You should set up an exception breakpoint and see what the actual error message is.

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: A few things. It's a pain to manually add frameworks. You should create a podFile and let the cocoaPods.app do everything for you. Secondly - are you opening your project from the .xcworkspace file instead of the .xcodeproj file?

Answer (score 1):

You are using RealmSwift, you need to be using Realm for Objective-C as well if you want to declare @objc dynamic var. The Object you're declaring needs to inherit from NSObject in order for that to work and the error you're seeing indicates that your object fails to implement certain required methods that are implemented by that super class.

Try adding both RealmSwift.framework and Realm.framework to your project.

Comment: I've added Realm and RealmSwift to an SDK and I've linked the SDK to a Sample App. I think that Realm and RealmSwift aren't carrying over to the Sample App.

Comment: Realm.framework seems to be missing if Object does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: and doesNotRecognizeSelector: . Both of those are implemented by NSObject.

Comment: Do you know how to make sure the pods are included in the SDK.framework? I've updated my question to show the linked frameworks and libraries.

Comment: I would first try and follow the instructions here and add Realm manually as a dynamic library. https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#dynamic-install if your issues are resolved then it's safe to say it isn't properly linking.